# Java EE I write the code with welcome-file-list in web.xml but do not effect

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, configuration

I want distribute some example Java EE to server with welcome file:
I find the 404 http://kitchensink-justexample.rhcloud.com/
but I could visit the http://kitchensink-justexample.rhcloud.com/index.jsf
I write the welcome-file-list in my web.xml, but it seems do not work.

my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Activate the JSF 2.0 servlet -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <!-- Tell the context which URLs to process with JSF -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


 <welcome-file-list>

  <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How to make the welcom-file-list work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with jsf before. But, I think the reason for this behavior is you have specified url pattern as *.jsf and the first url you are trying does not satisfy this pattern.